# WS should return only JSON not XML wrapped JSON

Tags: c#, json, web-services

I have a WS which should return only JSON, however its being wrapped in a XML.
Already removed the

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://www.url.com/")]
```

But it has no affect, my WS looks like this

```
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class pointer : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string HelloWorld(string name)
    {
        Account account = new Account
        {
            Email = "james@example.com",
            Active = true,
            CreatedDate = new DateTime(2013, 1, 20, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc),
            Roles = new List<string>
              {
                "User",
                "Admin"
              }
        };
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(account, Formatting.Indented);
        //return "Hello World";
    }
```

the return looks like this:

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

```
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
{ "Email": "james@example.com", "Active": true, "CreatedDate": "2013-01-20T00:00:00Z", "Roles": [ "User", "Admin" ] }
</string>
```

my config looks like this:

```
<configuration>
<system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
        <webServices>
            <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="500000000"/>
        </webServices>
    </scripting>
</system.web.extensions>
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory"
             verb="*" path="*.asmx"
             type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
             resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
<system.web>
    <webServices>
        <protocols>
            <add name="HttpGet"/>
            <add name="HttpPost"/>
        </protocols>
    </webServices>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.0" />
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument enabled="true">
        <files>
            <clear />
            <add value="pointer.asmx" />
            <add value="default.aspx" />
        </files>
    </defaultDocument>
    <security>
        <authorization>
            <add accessType="Allow" users="?" />
        </authorization>
    </security>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
    <!--<handlers accessPolicy="Read, Execute, Script" />-->
</system.webServer>
```

Is there anyway to keep the wrappers away and just return JSON?

Answer (score 0):

The ScriptService automatically serialize the result to JSON, you dont have to do it manually, otherwise it gets serialized twice. I think the content-type from the client is specifying application/xml instead of application/json?

Comment: No its             httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8;";